# Using Bing map into Mapbox iOS SDK

Tags: swift, bing-maps, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-ios

I am using Mapbox SDK because I want customised map display for particular park with custom tracks and labels. Mapbox allows such customisations easily but I found that Mapbox has low resolution aerial view for certain locations I am working upon than Bing Maps.

Is it possible to load Bing Maps as base for Mapbox styles? We need to create style from Mapbox studio and in Mapbox iOS SDK we are using this style URL like shown in code here.

```
let url = URL(string: "mapbox://{STYLE URL}")
let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: url)
mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
mapView.delegate = self
        
view.addSubview(mapView)
```

Can we add Bing Maps anyhow for such style via coding or from Mapbox studio?

Can we utilise this example to load Bing map?
https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/source-custom-raster/

I have accessed certain Bing Map APIs.

API to get Aerial imagery for Location: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-imagery-metadata#get-aerial-imagery-metadata-at-street-level

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/directly-accessing-the-bing-maps-tiles

Can we utilise these APIs or have any better option than this?

Following images show differences between coverage for both maps.

Bing Map:

[image]

Mapbox Map:

[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but there is a Bing iOS SDK available here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/sdk-native/ that supports full style customization, has full support for all bing imagery including 3D views that might work for you.

Comment: I don't want to integrate full bing SDK for iOS app because I already do have customised park styles for Mapbox SDK and it's a quite flexible to prepare styles into Mapbox Studio. Mapbox allows us to use some other raster sources but don't know how to utilise bing aerial imagery.

Comment: While it might be possible to get Bing imagery loading in the MapBox control, terms of use will require you to display additional attribution and copyright on the map and also call the imagery service with each session for proper billing and logging. There is a full style customization app similar to MapBox studio available for the Bing control as well. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/map-style-sheet-editor/9nbhtcjt72ft

Comment: Thanks but this style editor is not working on mac I believe :(

Comment: Here's an example for mapbox-gl-js:
https://github.com/kepta/idly/wiki/examples#using-bing-satellite-map

Comment: Still I am waiting to close this as I don't get bing imagery working with Mapbox :(.

Comment: @stdob-- I am using Swift and need to load Bing imagery with Mapbox's iOS View. Code above seems to be working for Javascript and I believe style customisation of this level is not possible with iOS framework